# Show a large image that can scroll into a smaller viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show a large image into a smaller div, enabling scrolling horizontally to view it. The outer div should extend up to the viewport size (which can be variable, depending on devices), but not more than it.

I have tried this way:

```css
    #outer-div {
        max-width:300px;  //just a guess, but I need the exact viewport size here
        overflow:auto; 
    }
    
    img {
       position: absolute;
       left: 50%;
       -webkit-transform:  translateX(-50%);
    }
```

```html
    <div id="outer-div">
        <img name="slideImg" src="https://socrates.dyndns-server.com/meteosurf/previsioni/0000.GIF"  border=0>'
    </div>
```

with no luck...
This is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxu5913c/).

Comment: You should include your HTML here too.  A fiddle would be even better.

Comment: Provide the necessary HTML in the question to replicate the issue you're having. You can edit your question and use the inline snippet tool to provide a runnable snippet. Without this, your question may likely be downvoted or closed. @jmargolisvt Assuming "fiddle" means JSFiddle - please do not suggest that users provide their examples using external resources. The code to replicate the issue must be included **in the question itself**. Things like JSFiddle should really just be used as a supplement.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Even better than a Fiddle would be to post a snippet right here. External links can become dead over time.

Comment: @Pete Because the parent of the `div` could have a width that is wider than the viewport set for it.

Comment: edited question including html and jsfiddle, but the viewport problem is difficult to replicate.

Comment: @Pete Knowing that the one constant in coding is change, I repeat my answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Your answer assumes there is a parent bigger than the viewport, given the code provided then width 100% will work also why are you answering questions I am putting to the OP, I want to know why the OP can't use it, not why you think the OP can't use it

Comment: @Pete No, my answer ensures that the `outer-div` can never be wider than the viewport, regardless of the size of the parent, now or in the future. In other words, my answer is scalable.

Comment: @Pete I'm not sure I see any distinction between the two. 100% certainly works when you absolutely know the parent's width is always going to be the viewport with. But, that's not a scalable solution, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is constrain the size of the image container element (I assume `outer-div` here) and then set that container's overflow.

To set the `max-width` to the viewport width, use: `max-width:100vw;`

```js
$(function(){
  var imgWidth = document.querySelector("#outer-div img").width;
  // Scroll the container 1/2 the width of the image
  $("#outer-div").scrollLeft((imgWidth - $("#outer-div").width()) / 2);
});
```

```css
#outer-div {
    max-width:100vw; /* No wider than 100% of the viewport width */
    overflow-X:scroll; /* show scroll bar for horizontal scrolling */  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer-div">
  <img src="http://study.com/cimages/videopreview/types-of-weather-maps-imagesscreen_169365.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I set (as default) showing the image at 50% horizontal scroll?

Comment: @FabioMarzocca Do you mean you want to push the image to the right 50% of the width of the parent?

Comment: No, I meant to center horizontally the image in the div (viewport)

Comment: @FabioMarzocca Updated with better answer to auto-scroll 1/2 the image width.

Comment: great! Thanks again